# Access Dropdown Box Value When changed via JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Hey, can you help me figure this out? I need to hide/show a div based on a dropdown box (the dropdown box only has a name, no id). If the value of the dropdown box is 2, it needs to be shown and for anything else it needs to be hidden. Here is what I have so far, but it doesn't seem to work (I tried using similar code on a checkbox and it worked fine, so obviously i'm missing something). (It's not possible to modify the dropdown box's code)

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#addons').hide();

$("input[name='configoption[1]']").change(function() {
        if($(this).val() != 2) {
                $('#addons').hide();
        } else
                $('#addons').show();
        } );
});

});
```

HTML

```
<select name="configoption[1]"> 
<option value="1" selected="selected">Test 1</option> 
<option value="2">Test 2</option> 
</select>
<div id="addons">
Hi
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you just simply specified the wrong element name, `input` should be `select`.

```
$("select[name='configoption[1]']")
```

make sure you are getting the element by doing this:

```
alert( $("select[name='configoption[1]']").length )
```

it should be anything other than `0`.

Comment: I got it, it was just a syntax error. I changed the input to select, and I fixed up the }); stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Use an onchange option. Change

`<select name="configoption[1]">`

to

`<select name="configoption[1]" onchange="javascript:function;">`

Comment: Sorry, just realized you said you can't change the html.